# C# Application deployment with unmanaged dlls from a PHP server

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I want to deploy a C# application from my website which is hosted in Linux/PHP Apache. It has a couple of managed and unmanaged dlls as dependencies. Can someone please tell if I can use ClikcOnce on Apache server, and if yes how I will be able to do it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click once only produce static files.

just check if the server will correctly serve all files (as content).

[edit] to conclude the comments, the 1&1 hosting provider php offer does not block files for a click once setup

Comment: thanks for your reply. my site is hosted on 1and1. I tried searching in google for 1and1  clickonce, but no relevant results show up. is there an easy way to verify if it will be supported by the server?

Comment: simply try it :) if you have already subscribed to the hosting

Comment: you are lucky. I'm also customer of 1&1 php hosting for my blog. I've tested : http://blog.hand-net.com/test/publish.htm and it works

Comment: no pb:) answer yourself to some questions and the reputation will grow up